# TStringGrid OnDrawCell Issue

Tags: c++, c++builder-xe4

I'm experiencing an issue ussing Drawcell on a TStringGrid with C++ Buidler XE4.
In a portion of my C++ code i put some text in cells like in the folowing lines:

```
StringGrid1->Cells[x][y] = "1.0";
```

And in the DrawCell Event when i do this :

```
UnicodeString tmp = StringGrid1->Cells[ACol][ARow];
```

tmp is "1" (when ACol = x and ARow = y). i am sure that **nowhere** in my code i replace the "1.0" in "1". So if anybody could explain me what's happen i will be very gracefull.

As i Experiment sometimes it work's and sometimes not (when recompiled).

Are the lower strats of C++Builder (which are delphi ones) sometimes swap (or something like that) the StringGrid behind the TStringGrid?

Comment: This simply does not happen, unless it's being changed in your code somewhere (or it's not being assigned as you think in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

What you describe cannot be reproduced. The `TStringGrid` control is know to work well. If you put a string into a cell, that same cell will come back until you modify it.

Most likely there is something else in your program that is modifying this. In order for you to track this down I suggest that you make an SSCCE. Once you do so you'll surely find the reason for your confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your respons. Like i said this code has worked but now doesn't so i will search on my SVN for buggy changes.